# What is the difference between "quand" and "lorsque"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, conjonctions

As far as i know, "quand" and "lorsque" have similiar meaning, "when". So what is the difference and when to use them?

Comment: At first sight, "lorsque" is more formal. I wouldn't use it in an everyday oral conversation...

Comment: @Random thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Larousse dictionary, "quand" and "lorsque" are synonyms.

Still according to the Larousse dictionary, the two words indicate the coincidence in time, a simultaneity.

In addition, the word "quand" corresponds to the English word "when" for a question while the word "lorsque" can't be used to translate the interrogative word "when".

Comment: "the coincidence in time" of what? The "questioning word when"? You mean the interrogative word when? By using non-standard terminology, it just gets even more confusing....I would not agree that quand and when indicate "the coincidence of time". They don't indicate coincidence (two things happenng at the same time). They indicate the occurrence of an event in time...

Comment: "Quand je suis arrivé, il faisait nuit" -> the two events "je suis arrivé" and "il faisait nuit" were happening at the same time (thus a coincidence)